# Mobile first with Magento

Tags: mobile

Does it make sense to use Magento as a backend for custom mobile apps? What is the speed of the API? Would I be able to use build in billing (at least use it to send invoices for example)? How about client records? Can I authorize clients with Magento API and store their details in Magento controlled database?

Comment: This is both subject to opinion (second question) and overly broad (all questions in context). Perhaps narrow your scope.